# Angular materials with Angular Reactive form, facing error

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms

I am working angular reactive forms with angular material but getting one error, its working fine in stackblitz but not in my local machine. Its showing something control with "confirm" is undefined. I am not able to figure why its showing.

```
 formControlName="confirm" shows error






 <form class="flex flex-column flex-row-ns flex-wrap mt2" [formGroup]="emailForm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit();"> 


<mat-form-field class="w-50-ns pr2-ns" formGroupName="userData">
    <mat-label>Email</mat-label>
    <input matInput type="email" placeholder=" Email address" formControlName="email" (blur)="suggestEmail()" />
    <mat-error *ngIf="f.invalid && f.touched && (f.errors?.email || f.errors?.required)">
      Please enter a valid email address
    </mat-error>
    <mat-error (click)="clickme()" *ngIf="f.invalid && f.touched && f.errors?.has_suggestion">
      Do you mean:
      <span class="text-color"> {{suggestedEmail}} </span>
    </mat-error>
  </mat-form-field>

          <mat-form-field class="w-50-ns pr2-ns">
              <mat-label>Confirm Email</mat-label>
              <input matInput type="text" formControlName="confirm" placeholder="confirm your email address" />
              <mat-error *ngIf="submitted && (isEmailMismatch || f.confirm?.errors)" class="invalid-feedback">
                  <mat-error *ngIf="f.touched && f.confirm?.errors.required">Confirm Email is required</mat-error>
                  <mat-error *ngIf="f.touched && isEmailMismatch">Emails must match</mat-error>
              </mat-error>
            </mat-form-field>
    </form>
```

Below is ts file

```
 submitted = false;
  public emailForm: FormGroup;
  suggestedEmail: string;
  email = new FormControl();
  confirm = new FormControl();

  constructor(private fb: FormBuilder) {
    super();
    this.emailForm = this.fb.group({

      userData: this.fb.group({
        email: [null, [Validators.required, Validators.email]],
        confirm: [null, [Validators.required, Validators.email]],
      }, {
          validator: (form: FormGroup) => { return form.get('email').value !== form.get('confirm').value ? { emailMismatch: true } : null }
        })
    });
  }
```

Error which I am facing is

```
ERROR Error: Cannot find control with name: 'confirm'
    at _throwError (forms.js:2094)
    at setUpControl (forms.js:2002)
    at FormGroupDirective.push../node_modules/@angular/forms/fesm5/forms.js.FormGroupDirective.addControl (forms.js:5168)
    at FormControlName.push../node_modules/@angular/forms/fesm5/forms.js.FormControlName._setUpControl (forms.js:5769)
    at FormControlName.push../node_modules/@angular/forms/fesm5/forms.js.FormControlName.ngOnChanges (forms.js:5690)
    at checkAndUpdateDirectiveInline (core.js:20661)
    at checkAndUpdateNodeInline (core.js:21929)
    at checkAndUpdateNode (core.js:21891)
    at debugCheckAndUpdateNode (core.js:22525)
    at debugCheckDirectivesFn (core.js:22485)
```

Comment: Well... in your template the `confirm` field is outside `userData` formgroup, and I guess you wouldn't even want to mark the formgroup on a mat-form-field

Comment: its inside, yes confirm is causing error

Comment: First I created stackblitz and then started implemented, its working here https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-email-checker-nynmj6?file=app%2Fapp.component.ts

Comment: Well, now you edited the post, but how it looked earlier `confirm` field was **clearly** outside the formgroup. And that it works in stackblitz doesn't help, there must be an error in your code. And I suspect it is like I said before you edited your question, that the `confirm` field was outside the group.

Comment: I am sorry for your confusion, later I realized only html with confirm causing error so I deleted unwanted html (which was for email). Also, i implemented same in my code which is showing same error

Comment: Yes, but look at the code you posted previously, `confirm` field is **outside** the formgroup, which would throw exactly that error. I assume that piece of code was your actual code, no? Please create a [mcve]

Comment: Did you use [formGroup]="emailForm" ??

Comment: @AJT_82 i dont see any form groups in template....

Comment: yes i used [formGroup] ="emailForm"

Comment: I dont know why its not able to find confirm

Comment: @Antoniossss In the original post there is a `formGroupName="userData"` on the mat-form-field, which only includes `email`

Comment: @Antoniossss and OP, dammit, here you see what I'm trying to explain :D ... https://imgur.com/a/rg71E5P

Comment: Yes, now you are showing the correct code. Look at your code... `confirm` should be INSIDE the `userData` formgroup, thus the error! I don't know how many ways I can say it :D

Comment: thanks, when said confirm should be inside userGroup I was looking at ts code.  adding this line  <mat-form-field class="w-50-ns pr2-ns" formGroupName="userData"> fixed my code. I am sorry for confusion

Comment: No problem, I guess there was confusion on all sides :D I see you got it just as I was writing answer. Felt I had to write one, so we could sort it out. Glad we did :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have excluded `confirm` formcontrol from your `userData` group, thus the error, it should be **inside** that formgroup, as you have marked it as such, so...

```
<div formGroupName="userData">
  <input matInput formControlName="email" />
  <input matInput formControlName="confirm"  />
</div>
```